# Finding the latest file from directory with creation date as suffix

Tags: shell

I have files in a directory having the name as /dir/file.$creation date in "yyyymmddhhmmss".
Now I want to pick up the file that was created latest in that directory based on the creation date using the "yyyyddmmhhmmss" part.

please suggest how this can be acheived using shell script.

I am using K Shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ls` and `sort` as follows:

```
ls dir/file.* | sort -n -t . -k 2 | tail -1
```

If you have too many files, the above command will fail will a "too many arguments" error, so use `find` instead:

```
find dir -name "file.*" -maxdepth 1 | sort -n -t. -k2 | tail -1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -t1 /IN/UR/DIR | head -1
```

Might work for you if it was created last...